# "Preferred" method to access webcam from C# in Windows Vista / 7

Tags: c#, api, webcam, directshow, wia

I've found plenty of posts discussing WIA, Windows Portable Devices API and DirectShow (and giving example code) for accessing a webcam from C# but when you research each method you seem to come across references that these are "old" methods.

So, question is, when running nothing earlier than Windows Vista, what is the "preferred" method for accessing a webcam from C#?

Thanks,

John.

Comment: Old does not mean bad.  Rather the opposite, nobody has managed to really improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Windows Media Fundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb970511%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Extracted from MSDN:

> Microsoft Media Foundation was introduced in Windows Vista as the replacement for DirectShow. Of course, DirectShow is still supported in Windows 7, but developers are encouraged to use Media Foundation in their new digital media applications.